# Select images in GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I have some photos in a GridView:

```
<GridView x:Name="lista" Padding="5">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Background="#FF3E3E3E">
                <Image Width="150" Height="220" Source="{Binding}" ></Image>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

How can i select multiple images from the GridView (like the FilePicker of Windows 10)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the `SelectionMode` property.

```
<GridView x:Name="lista" Padding="5" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Width="150" Height="220" Source="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Note that in the sample code provided, there's no need for a StackPanel (keep your visual tree as small as possible).

Comment: That's great thank you. You now how can i make GridView to show images in 3 columns?